# Alpha: true is not working in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a transparent renderer which was working fine in r77 of three.js but since the time I have updated it to 81dev it is no longer working. Please refer to the code below.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
```

I tried using three.min.js file from r77 to r81 and it alpha stops working from r80. Did the property name change? Can anyone help?

Comment: Whats the value of the `background` variable of your `scene`? Make sure it is `null`.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov Thanx man! It worked. I explicitly set the value to null and it fixed the problem.